# How to identify who is using Hardware Reserved Memory in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is all my extra RAM marked as “hardware reserved” in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/56157/why-is-all-my-extra-ram-marked-as-hardware-reserved-in-windows-7)

I run Windows 7 x86 Home Premium. I have an installed physical memory of 4 GB, out of which, 2.96 GB is usable (My Computer > Properties). I checked the memory usage using Resource Monitor and found 3036 MB / 4096 MB is available.

[image: resmon screenshot]

I noticed that 1060 MB is unavailable since it is reserved by some "Hardware component(s)". I would like to know which hardware component is using this 1060 MB. Is there any way or tool to identify this?

*Note: I know that Windows 7 Home Premium x86 supports a maximum of 4GB RAM.*

Comment: More information about the computer would need to be shared. More then likely most if not all of that memory is allocated to your graphics card.  The simple fact is your running a 32-bit operating system and there isn't a great deal you can do about the fact only 3036 is actually available and 1060MB is reserved to be used by I/O devices.

Comment: You may be able to get some of that memory back by turning memory remapping *off* in the BIOS.

Comment: @Ramhound is there any way or software to identify what exactly is using this memory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is all my extra RAM marked as "hardware reserved" in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/56157/why-is-all-my-extra-ram-marked-as-hardware-reserved-in-windows-7), also http://superuser.com/questions/205654/lenovo-t400-large-amount-of-memory-reserved-for-hardware?rq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/61007/hardware-reserved-memory-issue?rq=1, etc.

Comment: If your memory is mismatched, you can run into this.  See the various answers to the linked question.

Comment: @blasteralfred: It's windows for mapping hardware devices such as the GPU. If it's waste, you can get rid of it by turning memory remapping *off* in your BIOS. (The mappings are free under a 64-bit OS, so most modern BIOSes make lots of them. If you turn *off* remapping, the BIOS will know low memory is precious.)

Comment: @techie007 the question is asking for a "software / tool / way" to identify who is using the memory and not about memory mismatching.

Comment: @blasteralfred I agree with what you're saying, but the question it's based on (IMO) an incorrect assumption that there can be such a tool.. In most of the cases of the 'missing RAM' it's outside of the OS's access/view (reserved by hardware), so no software tools would be able to tell you what's going on with it.  But there may be another "way", and that's why it takes 5 to close; if others think it's worth keeping, it will stay. :)

Comment: Go to the device manager. Under `View`, select `Resources by type`. Then expand `Memory`. Note that the BIOS can shrink these mappings if you ask it to.

Comment: In my case it is 62 MB for Hardware reserved

Comment: RAMMap is what the OP wants:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx